# Can't read char from keyboard

Tags: c, input, scanf, fgets

I'm having trouble reading a char from my user.
The program I am trying to develop is a bank manager simulator where the user has multiple actions he can perform.
Problem is, after first reading from the user, the program seems to "skip" the `fgets()` line.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myBank.h"

int main(void){
  printf("Welcome to our bank!\n");
  char action[1];
  while (1)
  {

    //action = ' ';
    printf("\nHere is a list of actions you can preform:\n");
    printf("O\t Open a new account\n");
    printf("B\t Check balance\n");
    printf("D\t Make a deposit\n");
    printf("W\t Make a withdrawl\n");
    printf("C\t Close your account\n");
    printf("I\t Add interest to all accounts\n");
    printf("P\t Get info of all accounts\n");
    printf("E\t Close all accounts and end this program\n");

    fgets(action, 2, stdin);

    switch (action[0]) {
           case 'O':
               openAccount(); break;
           case 'B':
               checkBalance(); break;
           case 'D':
               deposit(); break;
           case 'W':
               withdraw(); break;
           case 'C':
               closeAccount(); break;
           case 'I':
               interest(); break;
           case 'P':
               print(); break;
           case 'E':
               end();
           default:
               printf("Invalid action was entered\n"); break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Originally I used `scanf()` instead but it caused the same issue.

Here is my input and output:

```
Welcome to our bank!

Here is a list of actions you can preform:
O    Open a new account
B    Check balance
D    Make a deposit
W    Make a withdrawl
C    Close your account
I    Add interest to all accounts
P    Get info of all accounts
E    Close all accounts and end this program
O
How much would you like to deposit?
f
Wrong input!

Here is a list of actions you can preform:
O    Open a new account
B    Check balance
D    Make a deposit
W    Make a withdrawl
C    Close your account
I    Add interest to all accounts
P    Get info of all accounts
E    Close all accounts and end this program
Invalid action was entered

Here is a list of actions you can preform:
O    Open a new account
B    Check balance
D    Make a deposit
W    Make a withdrawl
C    Close your account
I    Add interest to all accounts
P    Get info of all accounts
E    Close all accounts and end this program
Invalid action was entered

Here is a list of actions you can perform:
O    Open a new account
B    Check balance
D    Make a deposit
W    Make a withdrawal
C    Close your account
I    Add interest to all accounts
P    Get info of all accounts
E    Close all accounts and end this program
```

What I did was open a new account and enter a wrong input (char instead of int).
openAccount took care of the wrong input and returned to main but instead of showing the menu one more time, it shows it three more times.

Any help?

Comment: `action` is declared as an array of size 1.  `fgets` with a 2nd argument of 2 tries to write 2 characters into an array of size 1.  Bad things happen.

Comment: If you want to read a one character line into `action`, then the array must be at least size 3, and you should invoke `fgets(action, sizeof action, stdin)`. If the input is a single character line, that will write the character, a newline, and a null terminator. But if the input line has more than one character, the fgets will not consume the newline.